# How to Deserialize JSON in RestSharp?

Tags: c#, json, restsharp

I am just beginning developing using RestSharp and have hit an early roadblock.  I think once I understand this simple, but key, concept, I should be off and running.  I need to return an Access Token before making my standard calls later.  I have set up the following classes, generated from json2csharp.com:

```
    public class AccessToken
{
    public string Instance_Url { get; set; }
    public string Token { get; set; }
    public string Expiration_date { get; set; }
    public string Refresh_Token { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public AccessToken Access_Token { get; set; }
}
```

I have coded the following on a button click:

```
        var tokenclient = new RestClient();
        tokenclient.BaseUrl = "https://url";
        tokenclient.Authenticator = new HttpBasicAuthenticator("username", "password");
        var tokenrequest = new RestRequest(Method.GET);
        tokenrequest.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json;
        IRestResponse tokenresponse = tokenclient.Execute(tokenrequest);
        var content = tokenresponse.Content;
        RestSharp.Deserializers.JsonDeserializer deserial = new JsonDeserializer();
        var des = deserial.Deserialize<AccessToken>(tokenresponse);
```

I am able to return the following JSON as a string:

```
{
"Access_Token": {
"Instance_Url": "https://url",
"Token": "StringToken",
"Expiration_date": "9/30/2015 6:15:27 PM",
"Refresh_Token": "StringToken"
}
}
```

However, when I pull des.Token, it returns a blank value.  Can somebody kindly point out my error?

Comment: Did you try `deserial.Deserialize<RootObject>(tokenresponse)`?

Comment: Wow. I knew it was going to be simple. So instead of des.Token, it becomes des.Access_Token.Token...  Thank you!  You saved me a lot of head banging on my desk.

Comment: No problem, sometimes all you need is another pair of eyes

Comment: As a side-note, this is a one-liner with [my RestSharp alternative](http://tmenier.github.io/Flurl/): `var des = await "https://url".WithBasicAuth("username", "password").GetJsonAsync<AccessToken>();`

Answer (score 1):

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
var response = client.DownloadString(url + queryString);
ResponseModel<string> dataResponse = new ResponseModel<string>();
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(response))
{
        dataResponse = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ResponseModel<string>>(response);
}
```

Comment: I think the question is about doing it using RestSharp not "Newtonsoft.Json".